# Unit ball has empty interior in the weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider $ B_1:=\{ x \in \ell_1 : \|x\|_{\ell_1} < 1\}$ and $ B_2:=\{ x \in \ell_2 : \|x\|_{\ell_2} < 1\}$

i) Show that $B_1$ and $B_2$ have empty interior in their weak topology.

ii) Show that for any convergent sequence $x_n$ to a point $x$ of $B_1$ we have that $x_n$ is in $B_1$ ( in the weak topology $\sigma(\ell_1,\ell_{\infty}) $ )

iii) Show that for any convergent sequence $x_n$ to a point $x$ of $B_2$ we have that $x_n$ is in $B_2$ ( in the weak topology $\sigma(\ell_2,\ell_{2}) $ )

i) I have tried to suppose that there is a point in the interior but haven't reached any consistent result. So if I suppose there is a point inside then we have that there exists a $x$ in $\ell_{1}$ such that $\|x\|_{\ell_1}<1$ . But can't intuit to what contradiction get

ii)On the other hand here if I take a point in the ball and a sequence that converges to that point , I think that as it's open it should be inside also. But don't know if I am wrong about this.

Comment: In ii) and iii) for what $n$ do you want to show that $x_n$ is in the ball? It is certainly false that this holds for all $n$.

Comment: Actually , I thought this was for any $n$, at least there is nothing specified in the paper I have . Why it wouldn't be true for any $n$ and for what $n$ would be?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The result is true only if your space $X$ is infinite dimensional.

Answer for i): Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space and $x_0$ is an interior point of $\{x: \|x\|<1\}$. By definition of weak topology we can find $N \geq 1$, $r_i >0$ and $x_i^{*} \in X^{*}$ for $i=1,2...,N$ such that $|x_i^{*}(x)-x_i^{*}(x_0)| <r_i$ for all $i$ implies $\|x\|<1$. Put $x=x_0+ny$ where $y \in \cap _i\ker x_i^{*}$ and $n$ is a positive integer. You get $\|x_0+ny\|<1$ and this is true for all $n$. Hence $y=0$. It follows from this that $(x_1^{*},x_2^{*}.,,,x_N^{*}): X \to \mathbb R^{N}$  is an injective linear map. But then $X$ is finite dimensional.

Counter-example for iii) and ii): Consider $(y,x,x...)$ where $\|y\|>1$. This sequence converges weakly to $x$ but the first term of the sequence is not in the ball.

Comment: How can you assure that $y $ is in such intersection of the kernels ? I don't get why you can express $x$ in such way. And why if such map is injective is finite dimensional?

Comment: In the cases ii) and iii) I can take the elements $x_n$ fixedto get that, right? Is that what you mean?

Comment: The thing I don't understand is why such point $y$ exists in $\cap_i ker x_i^*$.

Comment: To prove that a linear map is  injective you start with a point in the kernel and show that it is $0$. For the linear map I have defined a point in the kernel  is simply a point which belongs to kernel of each $x_i^{*}$ @VeganMaths

Comment: Mmm, I see . In $ x= x_0 +ny$ , x is also in the ball ? This is the thing I don't understand quite enough , I mean, you make a traslation from $x_0$ to $x$ with $ny$ but I don't undertand why this is possible , why such $y$ exists and is also in the kernels

Comment: To see that $(y,x,x..)$ converges weakly to x , we have to see that $L(y_n,x_n,x_n)\rightarrow L( x ) $ So I go from several coordinates to one point only right?